# Unexpected change in Graphics in Elementary OS?

Tags: linux, graphics, themes

Recently I did installed "dconfeditor" in my Elementary OS. I restarted my Computer and log-in and see all the beautiful look of Elementary OS has gone. I really no idea why this happened to me, So, I have no information other than this. Please tell me what can I do to restore that old theme in my Elementary OS.

Here are my screenshots:-

Before->
[image: Image Before Change]

[image: Image Before Change]

After->
[image: Image After Change]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the solution that I found was to re-install the elementary-desktop

```
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop    
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: I had to purge first:
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop

Comment: Works, restart required.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem with the GTK themes. You should be able to fix this by installing `lxappearance` which is a program to change GTK themes and icon sets etc. and change back to the standard elementary theme.